# How to write not equal operator in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

```
using (RapidWorkflowDataContext context = new RapidWorkflowDataContext())
                    {
                        var query = from w in context.WorkflowInstances
                        from c in context.Workflows 
                         where EmpWorkflowIDs.Contains((int)w.ID) && w.CurrentStateID != c.LastStateID
                         select w;

                        return query.ToList();
                    }
```

I have 2 tables: Workflows and WorkflowInstances.

Workflows to store objects and workflowInstances to store instances.

Workflows Table: ID,Name,FirstStateID,LastStateID

WorkflowInstances Table: ID,Name,WorkflowID,CurrentStateID

How to write a query in linq to sql to select the instances from WorkflowInstances which CurrentStateID not equal LastStateID

Comment: And what's not working in your query?

Comment: You seem to have written a not-equal operator in linq. What's the problem you are having exactly?

Comment: I was confused between joining two tables in linq to sql because I am new with it :/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to revise the join to be on the related columns between the 2 tables, then you add your condition in the where clause, like the following:

```
using (RapidWorkflowDataContext context = new RapidWorkflowDataContext())
                        {
                            var query = from w in context.WorkflowInstances
                                        join c in context.Workflows on w.WorkflowID equals c.ID
                                         where EmpWorkflowIDs.Contains((int)w.ID)
                                         && w.CurrentStateID != c.LastStateID
                                         select w;

                            return query.ToList();
                        }
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using lambda expressions, then `not(!)` goes there:

```
.Where(p => !p.Whatever...)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as all other solutions here won't work with complex queries. When i first read this answer i didn't know what @erkaner was trying to say but its as easy as that: `from a in b join c in d into e from f in e.Where(....)`

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate `join` and it should be something like:

```
var query = from w in context.WorkflowInstances
            where !context.Workflows.Any(c => w.CurrentStateID != c.LastStateID) && EmpWorkflowIDs.Contains((int)w.ID)
            select w;
```