# how to write Query in LINQ For this below scenario

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

How To write Not equal Operator in sql to linq

```
select A.ID,B.TestName  from sampleTable A join TestTable b on A.ID<>B.ID.
```

Comment: How could you not find this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274141/how-to-wirte-not-equal-operator-in-linq-to-sql

Answer (score 0):

Try [!= operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx) this:

```
select A.ID,B.TestName  from sampleTable A join TestTable b on A.ID!=B.ID.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`!=`-Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tz250sf.aspx) (inequality operator)

```
 ... join TestTable B on A.ID != B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from a in context.sampleTable 
             join b in context.TestTable on a.ID != b.ID
             select new { a.ID, b.TestName }
```