# How to write a join with "not equal" in LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, join, linq-to-sql, equals

I have a table `employees` with the following columns

```
ID, Name, ..., RelatedID, ...
```

and i want to write the following select in LINQ to SQL:

```
select distinct b.ID, b.Name
from employees b
join employees a on a.RelatedID > 0
where b.id = a.RelatedID
```

I think the expression `a.RelatedID > 0` is basically a `0 not equals a.RelatedID` but the syntax is not supported.

Any ideas how to achieve my goal?

:edit

I have found a solution, see my posted answer.

Comment: This is an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  Instead of telling us the solution to whatever problem you're trying to solve and asking us to make it work, tell us the problem you're trying to solve and ask us for a solution.  What is this Linq statement supposed to accomplish?

Comment: Remember that any inner join can be written as a cross join with the on condition in the where clause.

Comment: So are you writing a linq statement or a SQL statement, I'm unsure what answer you would like providing :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write not equal operator in linq to sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18274141/how-to-write-not-equal-operator-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @juharr How would you write that query with a cross join? I tried `from b in employees 
    from a in employees  
    where a.RelatedID > 0 && b.ID == a.RelatedID
    select b` but it does not give the correct results (too many records are returned)

Comment: @ViRuSTriNiTy `... from emplyees b, emplyees a where a.RelatedID > 0 and b.id = a.RelatedID`.  Of course you could also just do an inner join and switch the on condition an the where clause.  But it sounds like your query isn't what you want in the first place.

Comment: @juharr I think you have misunderstood my question. I don't need the SQL statement, i need the LINQ to SQL query syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution myself, looks pretty ugly but it works:

```
from b in employees  
where (from a in employees where a.RelatedID > 0 select a.RelatedID).Contains(b.ID)
select b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just swap your `where` with your join filter.  You've put your actual join filter in your `Where` and your filtering as your join condition, hence your problems.

```
var query = from b in employees
    join a in employees on b.id equals a.RelatedID
    where b.RelatedID > 0
    select ...;
```

Note you may also want to be doing the filtering before you join (not sure if this would matter in SQL; it certainly would help in LINQ to objects)

```
var query = from b in employees
    where b.RelatedID > 0
    join a in employees on b.id equals a.RelatedID
    select ...;
```